# how to get mariadb compatible database from mysql db engine?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to export mysql databases that are compatible to mariadb engine.

```
sudo mysqldump -u root -p --compatible mariadb --all-databases --master-data > dbdump.sql
```

but running mysqsldump command throws this error,

```
Invalid mode to --compatible: mariadb
```

but when I typed mysql --help I do see it does have compatible flag listed.

Comment: is mariadb a valid option? might it need a version also? for example take a look at MariaDB documentation on the subject https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only use ansi as mode

> Produce output that is more compatible with other database systems or with older MySQL servers. The only permitted value for this option is ansi

Which means

> This mode changes syntax and behavior to conform more closely to standard SQL. It is one of the special combination modes listed at the end of this section.

But you should try it fiest with out options and see where it leads

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any specific compatibility options, MariaDB can import mysqldumps directly.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because `mariadb` is not a valid option since MySQL only permits `ansi` as a valid [option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible).

**--compatible=name**

> Produce output that is more compatible with other database systems or
> with older MySQL servers. **The only permitted value for this option is**
> **ansi**, which has the same meaning as the corresponding option for
> setting the server SQL mode. [See Section 5.1.11, “Server SQL Modes”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html).

On the other hand MariaDB has more [options](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/).